# Іншомовні запозичення, отримані не через російську за останні 25 років

Tags: запозичені-слова

Чи існує пряма взаємодія між українською та іншими мовами (передовсім, англійською, меншою мірою польською)? Чи є іншомовні слова, що ввійшли до української, але відсутні (або маловживані) в російській?

Так, можна згадати багато галицьких слів, що стали більш-менш популярними в загальноукраїнському просторі (як-от *пательня* чи *мати рацію* тощо), але, здається, вони ввійшли до галицької говірки ще до об’єднання.

Comment: Англійською - наприклад "еджайл-розробка" (Agile)?

Comment: Ґуґль показує Приблизна кількість результатів: 381 000 (0,59 сек.)  на запит "аджайл разработка"

Comment: @Artemix, може, воно теж прийшло через російську (спочатку до них, а потім через них до нас)? Тобто навряд, звісно, але у випадку слова, що прийшло одночасно до них і до нас — важко довести те чи інше. От знайти би пару прикладів, що прийгли **лише** до нас — це буде факт.

Answer (score 8):

Австралійські назви тварин: квол (Dasyurus), білбі (Macrotis), тилацин (Thylacinus), падемелон (Thylogale), намбат (Myrmecobius). Росіяни надають перевагу асоціативним назвам: квол – сумчаста куниця, білбі – кролячий бандикут, тилацин – сумчастий вовк, падемелон – філандер, намбат – сумчастий мурахоїд.

Answer (score 3):

На думку спадає лише сленгове ["лахати"](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53403/374967.html) з німецької lachen (сміятись). Чув його лише українською, російською ні.  Взагалі годі очікувати запозичень з мов, які не присутні у вжитку в Україні.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian.SE! Будь ласка, намагайтеся уникати суб'єктивних відповідей, які містять лише вашу власну думку і більш нічого. [Ось стаття](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5/), де ми описуємо, які дописи ми вважаємо якісними, а які — ні. Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, надавши більш аргументовану відповідь. Для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: Цікаво, що [тут](http://teenslang.su/content/лахать) наводять російський еквівалент. А [тут](http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=119357) кажуть про вживання слова на території України і Білорусі, але в російській мові.